# Truncate tweets for text classification

Tags: classification, natural-language

I have a binary classification tweet dataset with statistics as follows
average tweet length is 600.1 words
max tweet length is 3900 words
min tweet length is 40

I'm trying to classify the tweet using pre-trained BERT

So, to work with bert, I chose the maximum sequence length as 128 i.e.. each tweet token length is fixed to 128 tokens

So I'm truncating the data to 128 tokens and the performance of the bert model is almost 98% acc

But my question is that each tweet is very large but we are truncating to small tweet still the model is giving very good accuracy. I'm unable to understand how it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer you can get is that *it works when it works and it doesn't when it doesn't*. Obviously, you cannot truncate whatever text to whatever length with preserving the performance. To convince yourself, truncate the tweets to a single word, the performance would surely drop.

Moreover, how many tweets are there in your dataset that are longer than the truncation margin? Say that you have 1000 tweets and only one is longer than the truncation margin. Even if you replaced the tweet with completely random data it cannot technically change the accuracy by more than 1%.

Finally, it simply can be the case that the beginning of the text holds some kind of summary, lead, or otherwise important information, that is enough. This is a common practice in the written texts. Your dataset does *not* contain tweets (they are limited to 280 characters, so cannot consist of 3900 words), but more likely multiple tweets glued together. Since first tweet in the series would be displayed more, users would often put important information there and continue in the subsequent tweets. Hence, the beginning of the text may (but does not have to) contain enough of the important information for it to work.